# The process "git status -s" exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I uploaded my laravel 8 application to cpanel and I am getting the following error

It is working in localhost but on server it is showing this error.

The process "git status -s" exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds.

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Maybe relevant? https://github.com/spatie/laravel-backup/issues/487

Comment: Thanks but it did not solve my problem.

Comment: So you ran `git status -s` from the terminal on your server, in the application directory and you got the error message _The process "git status -s" exceeded the timeout of 60 seconds._ Is that the issue?

Comment: I uploaded my app to a cpanel. The website working fine but if I try to login on the website it will display the error.

Comment: Do you have something special on your website that run `git status -s` when you login? It seems very odd to me.

Comment: No I dont have. I am thinking maybe it is taking too long to access the database but I am not too sure @ClémentBaconnier

Comment: Could be. As far as I remember most of shared server using cpanel, uses an external DB. Perhaps double check you did change `DB_HOST` with the address provided and run `php artisan cache:clear`? It's weird the message is `git status -s` though

Comment: it is really weird. This is the first time I am seeing this error @ClémentBaconnier. Thanks tho

Comment: Do you have any backtrace in the Laravel logs or any more information about this error, like where does it appear, ... ?

Comment: @felk any solutions found for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using this

```
use Symfony\Component\Process\Process;
```

it allows to set your own Timeout

```
$process->setTimeout(3600);
```

more in documentation

https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html